# R Error in validObject(.Object) when running as script, but not in console

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, rscript

The following code works fine in the R console (R 3.3.0):

```
m = system.file("external/pores_1.mtx", package = "Matrix")
x = Matrix::readMM(m)
```

I can put it in a script and it runs fine in R console as:

```
source("test.R")
```

However, when I execute it as `Rscript --vanilla test.R` or `Rscript test.R`, I get an error:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “dgTMatrix” object: Not a valid 'Mnumeric' class object
Calls: <Anonymous> -> new -> initialize -> initialize -> validObject
Execution halted
```

I don't know if this is related to that specific function. I am guessing this has something to do with how Rscript works, but I used it with various other libraries and functions previously and have never seen anything like this. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: I can't replicate this. Are you sure the R you are running is tied to the same version of Rscript you are running? Maybe try adding `library(methods)` to the script since Rscript doesn't load that by default.

Comment: Definitely the same version of R and Rscript (same `bin` and same `--version`).

Comment: Adding `library(methods)` worked. What happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm ... I'm getting the exact same error when running a script containing a call to `glmnet()`. I was able to trace it back to the Matrix package, on which glmnet depends.

I back-rev'd my R version from v3.3.3 -> v3.3.2 and the error disappeared. I then checked the `sessionInfo()` between the two and discovered that the version of the `Matrix` package differed ... it is 1.2-8 (in v3.3.3) and 1.2-7.1 (in v3.3.2). To confirm, I simply replaced the "OK" version of Matrix (7.1) with the "broken" version and the error returned.

I can also confirm that explicitly loading the methods package via `library(methods)` resolves the error (somehow?), which explains the differing behavior between the console call and the Rscript call from the command line.

So, it appears we have 2 work-arounds:

1. `library(methods)`
2. back rev your version of Matrix to 1.2-7.1.

Neither is super satisfactory ... I'd just like to know what's going on with Matrix 1.2-8. Maybe it'll be bug-fixed in the next version.

If you're interested, here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  base

other attached packages:
[1] glmnet_2.0-5  foreach_1.4.3 Matrix_1.2-8 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-15 grid_3.3.3       iterators_1.0.8  methods_3.3.3   

[5] lattice_0.20-35
```

Comment: I was also using Matrix 1.2-8, so it makes more sense now. I still have no idea why executing using Rscript makes a difference.

Comment: It makes a difference because `methods` is not attached when you "kick" a script via the `Rscript` command, but it IS loaded on a standard R startup. The environments are close, but not identical (which previously I had assumed!).

Compare:
`Rscript --vanilla -e "sessionInfo()"`
to
`R --vanilla (start R session)`
`sessionInfo()`

The methods package is attached in the latter but not the former.

Comment: thanks for clarifying! I didn't know that. I am surprised `methods` wasn't loaded by any other packages. I initially encountered this problem even after loading a few packages.

Comment: Was news to me too. Lesson learned. It still doesn't answer what changed in Matrix_1.2-8 however. That's still a mystery. At least there is a work around until a bug fix is released.

Answer (score 2):

Oh dear.
I'm pretty (not 100% !) sure that this problem should not apply in newer version of R and Matrix.
Still I would claim this is *not* a Matrix bug in a proper sense, rather either an 'Rscript' vs 'R' bug -- as @Stu Field  mentions already;  `Rscript` does not by default attach the `methods` package to the `search()` path,  but regular R does.

OTOH, `R CMD check Matrix` nowadays should try to run Matrix without the methods package being in the search path, and hence the problem should not be present from Matrix 1.2-9 and newer, i.e., by default from R 3.4.0 and newer or then update the 'Matrix' package if you have an older version of R.

Again: Can  you please confirm that the problem is gone with R 3.4.0 (which has Matrix 1.2-9 "along with it") ?

Here is a more useful example script, I called  `Rscript-tst.R`.
Run as

```
Rscript --vanilla Rscript-tst.R > Rscript-tst.Rout 2>&1
```

or (as myself with many R versions installed) something like

```
`R-3.4.0 RHOME`/bin/Rscript --vanilla Rscript-tst.R > Rscript-tst.Rout_R340 2>&1
```

`Rscript-tst.R` :

```
options(echo = TRUE)# << even with "Rscript" or --slave ...
(m <- system.file("external/pores_1.mtx", package = "Matrix"))
packageDescription("Matrix")
## This *load*s the Matrix package but does not attach it to search()
str(Matrix::readMM)
sessionInfo()
x <- Matrix::readMM(m)
## used to fail because 'methods' was not "there" (in Rscript only)
```